# Backref package for page reference

Tags: bibliographies, back-referencing

I'm using the `backref` package within the `hyperref` package:

```
\usepackage[backref]{hyperref}
```

I get the following result:

```
Philip Hall. On representatives of subsets. Journal of the LMS, 10, 1935. 3.2, 4.1
```

where `3.2` and `4.1` are hyperlinks to sections in which this bibliographic entry is referenced. Is it possible to get pages instead of sections?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use

```
\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}
```

instead of

```
\usepackage[backref]{hyperref}
```

Comment: Ah, seems like `\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}` also works!